# Problems with Chrome in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, java, lastpass

Since  I upragraded to Ubuntu 13.10, my Chrome (Chromium, actually) is misbehaving. LastPass does not work, some Java-enabled pages (the New York Times, for instance) crash. Does anyone know why, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, new version is not stable as that of the LTS version. Also chromium is a project from google it is not stable. It is for the testing purposes to make the next version of google chrome more stable. So it might have buggs. In my opinion use 12.04 LTS with google chrome.